# how to use javascript replace all of it?

Tags: javascript

the style is `@XXX` 
now i want to replace all of it to `<a href='XXX'>@XXX</a>`.
how should i do? thank you.
XXX is the url

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for, but this is how you would wrap `@XXX` --where `X` is any sequence of the letters A-Z case-insensitive -- with the link tag:

```
var orig = "Please go to the @index page."
var re = /@([a-z]+)/gi;
var template = "<a href='$1'>@$1</a>";
alert(orig.replace(re, template));
// alerts "Please go to the <a href='index'>@index</a> page."
```

- `@` matches `@`
- `([a-z]+)` matches any sequence of one or more letters and stores them in a backreference (the `$1` in the `template` variable)
- `/g` makes the search global, instead of just finding the first match and replacing it
- `/i` makes the search case-insensitive

You could expand the example to include symbols like `/` and `.` and numbers with something like `/@([a-z0-9/.]+)/gi` (note: `/` and `.` don't need to be escaped as part of a character class).

Comment: +1 but i think you should explain the global flag you used because this seems to be what the OP is asking for

Comment: @Ibu, true. Added info on `/g` to my answer.

Comment: for some reason I recall that it's better to do `a-zA-Z` w/o the insensitive flag; perhaps that's a dated re optimization technique, though

Answer (score 0):

A very quick answer and reference to you.

In JavaScript, strings have a replace method:

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp