# Searching for values in string, then updating the string

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATE 1:**

Really sorry about this, I just realised I made a mistake with the question.

If `data` = `some @text1 here, and @text2 here`

It should become

`some <a href="http://www.google.com/?q=text1">@text1</a> here, and <a href="http://www.google.com/?q=text2">@text2</a> here`

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

Using jQuery AJAX, I am returning `data` and outputting it like this:

`$('.class_name_here').append( data )`

Within `data` I want to be able to search for certain characters, then add urls to them before outputting them, e.g.

lets say `data` contains

`some @test here`

I want to find the word which follows after `@` and add `http://www.google.com` to it, so I end up with

`some <a href="http://www.google.com">@test</a> here`

Comment: I answered a similar question ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488228/how-to-use-javascript-replace-all-of-it/6488272#6488272)) a few days ago. It would work the same in your case if you just change the replacement template to `"<a href='http://www.google.com/'>@$1</a>"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var str = 'test @google test';
str = str.replace(/(@\w+)/g,'<a href="http://google.com/">$1</a>');
alert(str);
```

Should work, a simple regex replace. And a nice demo [can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/HKpc7/2/).

#### Update:

Try this on for size:

```
// place somewhere in global scope (in head of document for instance)
String.prototype.addGoogleLinks = function(){
    return this.replace(/(@(\w+))/g,'<a href="http://google.com/?q=$2">$1</a>');
};

// reference the data variable and call the addGoogleLinks()
// which will return the formatted string
data.addGoogleLinks()
```

That will wrap all `@keywords` in a `<a href="http://google.com/?q=keywords">@keywords</a>`, for instance.

[Demo of this, too](http://jsfiddle.net/HKpc7/3/)

Comment: Updated question.  Really sorry about this, I only realized the mistake I made in the question after you posted a solution.

Comment: @oshirowanen: You can still use this answer, just read a bit about regular expressions and adjust what he's posted to match your needs.

Comment: @patrick: Just caught that. I used ctrl+x, not ctrl+c when I dup'd the code to the answer. ;-) Oops! -- Links are now up-to-date

Answer (score 1):

In response to your updated question. Again, this is mostly a slightly modified repeat of a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488228/how-to-use-javascript-replace-all-of-it/6488272#6488272) I gave:

```
function googlify(text) {
  return text.replace(/@(\w+)/g,
                      "<a href=\"http://www.google.com/?q=$1\">@$1</a>");
}

alert(googlify("some @text1 here, and @text2 here"));
// Alerts "some <a href="http://www.google.com/?q=text1">@text1</a> here,
//         and <a href="http://www.google.com/?q=text2">@text2</a> here"
```